# On Click Change Multiple Div Classes in Current Div Only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

Help Needed

I have some sets of divisions available, where all of the div's are with the same classes. Each div contains a button and some other div's.

```
<div class="red box border">
    <button class="changecolo">change</button>
    <div class="sb">t</div>
    <div class="box-small yellow">A</div>
</div>
<div class="red box border">
    <button class="changecolo">change</button>
    <div class="sb">t</div>
    <div class="box-small yellow">A</div>
</div>
<div class="red box border">
    <button class="changecolo">change</button>
    <div class="sb">t</div>
    <div class="box-small yellow">A</div>
</div>
```

and the css used

```
.box {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:block;
    margin:5px;
    float:left;
}
.box-small {
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    display:block;
    margin:5px;
    float:left;
}
.sb {
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    display:block;
    margin:5px;
    float:left;
}

.red {background-color:red;}
.yellow {background-color:yellow;}
.border{border:1px solid #000;}
```

Now, when i click on the button inside the div, the div with 'box-small' class has to be changed. It works with the following jQuery.

```
$('.changecolo').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest(function(){
        $('.box-small').removeClass('yellow');
        $('.box-small').addClass('red');
    });
});
```

but the problem is when i click on the button, styles for all the divs are changing. I want to change the current divs class only.

You can find the Fiddle for the same here http://jsfiddle.net/om749rbd/6/

Your valuable help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of `closest()` is incorrect, try giving it a selector instead of a function. From there you can use `$this.find()` to get the `.box-small` elements. You can also use `toggleClass()` to change between the classes on each successive click. Try this:

```
$('.changecolo').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('.box').find('.box-small').toggleClass('yellow red');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/om749rbd/13/)

Comment: toggleClass will add class `yellow` if not present, the asker want to remove it. Same for `red`.

Comment: I still love the `addClass` and `removeClass` chaining if there are only two classes. It makes the code more readable.

Comment: @Tusher that's correct, this is a toggle which is more in keeping with having a button that's always visible.

Comment: @Vijay true, but that means that the button will only work once. This way the button will always have the 'change colour' effect as the label states. It can easily be changed if this isn't the behaviour the OP wanted. I'm just showing alternatives.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan helped a lot, thank you very much for the prompt solution. I was surprised with the response in stackoverflow. Really find a great place where awesome people stay :)

Answer (score 2):

In your `click` event handler add the following code.

```
$(this).closest('.box').find('.box-small').removeClass('yellow').addClass('red');
```

This will find the closest *parent* having class `box` and then find the descendant having class `box-small` and then change the class of this element.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/oerepbf2/)

```js
$('.changecolo').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.box').find('.box-small').removeClass('yellow').addClass('red');
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}
.box-small {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}
.sb {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.border {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="red box border">
  <button class="changecolo">change</button>
  <div class="sb">t</div>
  <div class="box-small yellow">A</div>
</div>
<div class="red box border">
  <button class="changecolo">change</button>
  <div class="sb">t</div>
  <div class="box-small yellow">A</div>
</div>
<div class="red box border">
  <button class="changecolo">change</button>
  <div class="sb">t</div>
  <div class="box-small yellow">A</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AmmarCSE this will work fine - even the original version before the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.siblings()` in jquery `.closest()` is not work in your context.

```
$('.changecolo').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.siblings('.box-small').removeClass('yellow').addClass('red');
});
```

or

```
$('.changecolo').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.siblings('.box-small').toggleClass('yellow red');
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/om749rbd/12/)

Comment: Using `next().next()` will make it stick to the current HTML structure. If the HTML changes it would not work. The best approach should be `closest()` and `find()`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$(this).closest()` to get the parent div and then target the specific div using `find()`

Check the [CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/om749rbd/15/)

```
$('.changecolo').click(function () {
   var $this = $(this);
   var boxSmall = $this.closest('div').find('.box-small');
   boxSmall.removeClass('yellow').addClass('red');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use $this selector(if HTML structure doesnt change) to get the next sibling like this:

```
$('.changecolo').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.closest(function(){
            $this.next().next().removeClass('yellow');
           $this.next().next().addClass('red');
        });
    });
```

Update fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/om749rbd/11/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.changecolo').click(function () {
    var that = $(this).siblings('.box-small');
    $(that).removeClass('yellow');
    $(that).addClass('red');

});
```

[updates demo](http://jsfiddle.net/om749rbd/16/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

**Script**

```
$('.changecolo').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.box').find('.box-small').removeClass('yellow').addClass('red');
});
```